# how can I replicate this on vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm trying to replicate this on Vue, the date is coming from an array
I have something like this

```
<h1>{{ mydate | formatDate }}</h1
```

Comment: You can use the external library https://date-fns.org/

Comment: You should not use a filter, prefer using a computed rather because it is deprecated in Vue3. And both are pretty much doing the same thing too. Otherwise yeah, any date library should do it (just don't use Moment.js).

Comment: @kissu the item is coming from an array on an API, how should I do it on computed?

Comment: @Thescion the library can add the styles as well?

Comment: Not sure what would be the issue to use [a computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example). `mydate` is somewhere in your `.vue` file? Alright, then you can go from `mydate` to `myComputedDate` or alike, while applying the formatting. And no, `date-fns` is library for dates. If you want to have some yellow text and stuff below, CSS is the way to go.